# bash unable to interpret cli command that uses curly braces in GitHub Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, aws, github

**What specific syntax needs to be changed in the `aws s3api` cli command below in order for the bash shell to interpret the command properly?**

The environment is an ubuntu-latest GitHub runner executing a GitHub workflow using a bash shell.

The command that is breaking in the GitHub Ubuntu runner is:

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket s3.bucket.name --key filename.tar.gz --tagging TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}
```

The error being thrown is:

```
Unknown options: TagSet=Value=yes
```

The same identical command works perfectly in a windows laptop using cmd.exe, so the code is a valid aws cli command.

The problem might be related to the GitHub workflow syntax for environment variables in bash which looks like ${envVarName}.  Or is something else the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to quote your arguments:

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket s3.bucket.name --key filename.tar.gz \
  --tagging "TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}"
```

The syntax `{a,b,c}` in bash indicates brace expansion:

> Brace expansion is a mechanism by which arbitrary strings may be generated. This mechanism is similar to pathname expansion, but the filenames generated need not exist. Patterns to be brace expanded take the form of an optional preamble, followed by either a series of comma-separated strings or a sequence expression between a pair of braces, followed by an optional post‐script. The preamble is prefixed to each string contained within the braces, and the post‐script is then appended to each resulting string, expanding left to right. (from the `bash(1)` man page)

So if we write:

```
echo TagSet={Key=public,Value=yes}
```

We get as output:

```
TagSet=Key=public TagSet=Value=yes
```

By quoting the argument we inhibit brace expansion.